# Table having column with multiple rows having comma separated values, want to insert each value in column of other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

`enter code here`I need a query to insert. Maybe:

```
insert tblTestTable (TestData) 
select value from STRING_SPLIT((select MyData from tblMyTable), ',')
```

refer attachment[Refer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAqva.png)

Comment: Please edit your post and add some description of what you actually want to achieve. Sample data and expected result in tabular format would also help us better understand your issue.

Comment: Have you done any research? I can't believe you would be the first person to have a requirement like this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`CREATE TABLE TableA
(ColumnToSplit VARCHAR(500))
GO
INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT 'A,B,C'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A,F,G'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'D,E,H'
GO`

SELECT value 
FROM TableA 
 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ColumnToSplit, ',')
GO

Comment: thanks @ForStudy, please mark as useful if you can. ta :)